# Need to assign dynamically $config['base_url'] in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to assign `$config['base_url']` dynamically in `config.php` every time when url hits.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Is your site changing domain at each page?? ..Why do you want to change $config['base_url']? Leave it blanck and it will be fetched automatically anyway. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Of course, you would write a conditional inside of `config.php` and assign it as-you-see-fit. Though, I'm a little curious as to why you would want to do this. Please provide more information for us.

Comment: @JordanArseno and Damien Pirsy ..actually my codeigniter application will run several websites and when any of them url hit, i need to store that url specific part to $config['base_url']. well i have done it properly ..thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we are using $config['base_url'] to store domain name. Why you need to store this on every refresh?. If you want to make it dynamic on different domains. Try bellow one

```
 $config['base_url']=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. CodeIgniter's `base_url` requires the protocol + a mandatory trailing slash. The OP needs to supply more information before this question is truly answerable.