# make config['base_url'] dynamic

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I need to assign `$config['base_url']` dynamically in config.php as my site is running on different domain so need to change it accordingly.

I read this question but not getting valid answer [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650346/need-to-assign-dynamically-configbase-url-in-codeigniter) thanks.

Comment: `need to change it accordingly`, would you like to create an example, please ?

Comment: What is the point in posting a duplicate if you already know it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Michal I want the correct answer of this question so i post it again , so i do it correctly and in future any other need this question so get correct answer .

Comment: "Yo dawg, I heard that you like duplicates so i duplicated your duplicate so you can duplicate while duplicating" /xzibit

Comment: @Charlie it means as site url change it also change .

Comment: If the question asked the same way didn't get solved. Why would this?

Comment: @Akash I still don't see a reason to post a duplicate! Will you post it again in a couple of months if you get no answer that matches your expectations?

Comment: @Michal its funny what u saying ... i definately find a solution in the mean time ...

Answer (score 0):

check this
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

output:
www.example.com

so

```
$config['base_url'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Comment: is there any way to change URL from the admin panel as admin define it from back-end.

Answer (score 0):

I use this..

$config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';

Answer (score 0):

Akash, please be more clear in your question in the future. I only figured out what you are asking after reading the comment to Dorgladir's answer. You made no mention of an admin panel or backend in your question.

Create a library that loads before the others. For example, I use a Init/Startup library that's auto-loaded to perform common operations before other libraries and controllers load.

Use that library's constructor to retrieve the stored base_url from the database (or where ever you store it) and then set it with config->set_item.

Example:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
/* code here to retrieve url from database and set it to $stored_base_url */
$CI->config->set_item('base_url', $stored_base_url);
```

Anything loaded after that class will use the new base_url.